# What's wrong with this regex? JSLint is throwing an error

Tags: javascript, regex, jslint

I'm trying to validate my whole script **[through the new JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/)**, but with this:

```
function a() {
    'use strict';
    var string;
    string = string.replace(/\x00*/g, '');
}
```

It throws:

> **Unexpected 'x' after '\'.**
>
> ```
> string = string.replace(/\x00*/g, '');
> ```

The old version throws no errors with that. I realize that it's in beta, but I would expect that it works just as good as the old version. `\x00` stands for null character, by the way.

So, is it something that changed with ECMAScript 6? Is it just a JSLint bug? Am I actually doing something wrong?

Comment: with `/[\x00]*/g`  got no errors

Comment: Yeah, I had noticed that. Is it wrong to specify a regex character without the brackets?

Comment: @WilliamTheBaker—no. You might also use `/\u0000/` (which JSLint seems to like) since four digit hex values are [*specifically allowed*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-6) by ECMA-262, whereas two digit values like `\x00` aren't (as far as I can tell). However, that throws an error: "null is not an object", you have to use `/\u0000*/`.

Comment: Thanks. According to @nhahtdh, it is allowed. So `\0`, `\u0000` and `\x00` are all valid. I will use `\u0000` definitely, just because I want the validator to keep on going through my code, but maybe an issue can be raised in Github to see Douglas' opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to ECMAScript specification:

- `\x00` is valid, under the grammar expansion:

  ```
  Atom -> \ AtomEscape
  AtomEscape -> CharacterEscape
  CharacterEscape -> HexEscapeSequence
  HexEscapeSequence -> x HexDigit HexDigit
  ```

  and the pattern semantic:

  > The production `CharacterEscape :: HexEscapeSequence` evaluates by evaluating the CV of the `HexEscapeSequence` (see 7.8.4) and returning its character result.
- `\0` is always interpreted as matching the NUL character, under the pattern semantic of `DecimalEscape`:

  > The production `DecimalEscape :: DecimalIntegerLiteral [lookahead ∉ DecimalDigit]` evaluates as follows:
  >
  > 1. Let `i` be the MV of `DecimalIntegerLiteral`.
  > 2. If `i` is zero, return the `EscapeValue` consisting of a `<NUL>` character (Unicode value 0000).
  > 3. Return the `EscapeValue` consisting of the integer `i`.
  >
  > The definition of "the MV of `DecimalIntegerLiteral`" is in 7.8.3.
  >
  > <sub>**NOTE**  If `\` is followed by a decimal number `n` whose first digit is not 0, then the escape sequence is considered to be 
  >   a  backreference.  It  is  an  error  if  `n`  is  greater  than  the  total  number  of  left  capturing  parentheses  in  the  entire  regular 
  >   expression. `\0` represents the `<NUL>` character and cannot be followed by a decimal digit.</sub>

Therefore, I'm not sure why JSLint forbids these constructs. From some testing, it seems that they are not implemented in the parser, since simple codes like this:

```
var x = /(['"])\1/;
```

throws `"Unexpected '1' after '\'."` error.

If you want to get the code to pass JSLint, you can specify NUL character with `\u0000`. Otherwise, you can just ignore this error.

Comment: I think this explanation is as good as it gets. So, it is probably right to assume it is either a bug in the parser, or not implemented yet, because it is in beta. Did you find this in ECMA's documentation? May I have the link if it's not too much of a bother? I can't ignore it since since the parser stops in there and doesn't continue, so I guess I will just use `\u0000` meanwhile. Thanks!

Comment: @WilliamTheBaker: The text in quote are cited from the documentation. You can find the spec here: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/

Answer (score 3):

> The "A regular expression literal can be confused with '/='" error is thrown when JSLint, JSHint (prior to version 1.0.0) or ESLint encounters a regular expression literal that begins with the = character. In the following example we attempt to assign a regular expression literal to match the string "=1" to the variable x:
>
> This error is raised to highlight a potentially confusing piece of code. Your code will run fine if you do not fix this error, but it may be confusing to others, especially at first glance to someone quickly searching through your script.
>
> The / character is ambiguous in JavaScript. It can either signify the start or end of a regular expression literal, as it does in the example above, or it can be interpreted as the division operator. Like most of the arithmetic operators, the division operator can be combined with the assignment operator to produce a shorthand:

https://jslinterrors.com/a-regular-expression-literal-can-be-confused-with

So you need to use the `RegExp` constructor:

```
string.replace(new RegExp('\\x00*', 'g'), '');
```

Which outputs the same regex as the regex literal:

```
console.log(new RegExp('\\x00*', 'g').toString() === /\x00*/g.toString()); // true
```

Tip

NULL character `\x00` can be shortened to `\0` ([MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions))

```
new RegExp('\\0*', 'g')
```

--

Update

@nhahtdh's answer shows that you can use `/\u0000*/g` literal.

Comment: Well it says `0` now: `Unexpected '0' after '\'.` But the problem persists.

Comment: That throws `Unexpected '0' after '\'.` :p

Comment: I ran it through the command line jslint tool and did not get errors

Comment: @Moogs JS**H**int is not JS**L**int.

Comment: @WilliamTheBaker: JSLint probably doesn't like `\0`. It's valid according to ECMA specs

Comment: Did you run it through http://jslint.com or http://old.jslint.com ? The former validates it.

Comment: But why does it? Isn't the `/regex/flag` syntax valid? Also, in your update, aren't you escaping the `\\`, making it match the literal string?

Comment: @WilliamTheBaker no, do `console.log(new RegExp('\\0*', 'g'));` and it outputs `/\0*/g`. Read up on RegExp https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: @WilliamTheBaker https://jslinterrors.com/a-regular-expression-literal-can-be-confused-with

Comment: It doesn't actually complain about `string.replace(new RegExp('\0*', 'g'), '');` either, and that does the same as the regex with the double slash. `\x00` is also valid as the `null` character, because MDN says this about `\xhh`: 'Matches the character with the code hh (two hexadecimal digits)'. And `00` is the hex code for `null`.

Comment: "*And reason for JSLint error is because new JSLint expects it to be in a RegExp object*". You're speculating. ECMA-262 says using a literal is equivalent to using the constructor, they both produce exactly the same object (it would be rather strange if they didn't). If JSLint treats them any differently, that's a bug—or a code convention disliked by the author of JSLint, pure speculation of course. ;-).

Comment: @WilliamTheBaker you need the extra slash, otherwise it'll output `/*/g`

Comment: It does output that in the console, yes, I guess the console interprets it as a string, and because it is null, the slash doesn't show up. But if you try alerting or logging when running the `replace` on a string, both regexes do the same.

Comment: And that link is about `/=`, because yeah, it looks like division, but `/\0` doesn't fall under that, I would guess. Neither does `/\x00`.

Comment: @RobG, yeah, I wouldn't see why that would be. The old JSLint approves of the syntax, and they're pretty much the same. It is also weird, because like @Deadooshka pointed out `/[\x00]*/g` doesn't throw any errors, and without using the `Regex` constructor. I mean, it is kind of more correct, I think? Becuase the square brackets are for enclosing characters, and the null char is a char, but I thought that specifying a char without the brackets is still valid regex?

Comment: @Moogs, thanks for the effort in researching this. This answer gives a way to circumvent the issue, so I'd really like to upvote this, but I can't because of my reputation.

Comment: Also, I just saw the edit. I'm still not fully convinced with it being because of that. I mean, the error is happening because of a char after \ and not because the expression starts with /, plus, the regex doesn't start with `=`

Comment: @WilliamTheBaker yeah I don't know what to say, looks like the new JSLint has weird holes in it. JSHint is the way to go in my opinion because it's contributed to by the community rather than 1 guy.

Comment: Yeah, will check that out too. Apparently this new jsHint doesn't like for loops either. I don't know if I can accept that :p. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Luckily there's a directive for `for`. ;^) The new JSLint does have some unexpected holes, and sometimes [stuff was just plain missing](https://plus.google.com/+VincentSchoettke/posts/NSnY8pq8dLk), which Crockford fixed quickly once it was pointed out. Might be worth giving him a yell over on that [Google+ forum](https://plus.google.com/communities/104441363299760713736).